# How to pass a lambda to link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to use lambda as a parameter for link_to for the code below: edit.html.erb

```
<h2>Edit customer info</h2>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to(@return_to) do %>
  Back
  step_back()
<% end %>
```

Here is the def for step_back:

```
  #return link for previous page in page step
  def step_back
    session[:page_step] -= 1
  end
```

The problem with the code above is that the step_back() is executed as soon as the edit.html.erb is loaded. Actually the step_back should only be executed when the user clicks the Back link. I figure that only lambda can accomplish this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Client side code == javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your options are limited since you're interacting with the session.

You're getting that `@return_to` from somewhere; it'd probably be easiest to call an action that gets the same data and redirects to it, and does the same session manipulation.

Comment: I am trying to avoid the immediate execution after erb loading. The execution should only happen when the user clicks Back link.    Any suggestions about how to record the viewing history and providing Back/Cancel for application? Rails :back does not work properly with action such as edit.

Comment: @user938363 I understand what you're trying to do, and I gave the solution--if you want to execute server-side code on the click of a link, then you need to actually call the server on the click of the link and do it then. Right now you're mixing up when things get executed.

Comment: "you need to actually call the server on the click of the link and do it then". Please elaborate.

Comment: @user938363 Elaborate how? The template is executed before it's sent to the browser: even if you had a lambda, it's too late.

Answer (score 0):

See about writing your step_back() function in javascript and attaching it to an onClick html attribute on an  tag instead of using the link_to rails helper

Then also .preventDefault() the event with javascript if you don't want the link to go anywhere, or to '#'

This will allow the code to execute on the click event in the browser and not during asset compilation before the page is served.